# How to write a book that is a compilation of letters

Tags: books, letters

I would like to write a book in LaTeX that is a compilation of several letters.

I tried the following approach:

- The main document is a book type:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\title{TITLE}
\author{ME}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{1942}
\section{Julio}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}]{Carta1}
\end{document}
```

- That main document includes a PDF page obtained from `Carta1.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}
\longindentation=0pt 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\signature{Me}
\address{This place}
\date{1 1 1111}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}
\opening{Dear you:}
\dots
\closing{Bye,}
\ps{PS}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

However, this approach is not usable for me due to the following reasons:

1. Each letter comes from a PDF, which means that it will be inserted in a different page in the main document. In this way, when there is a new chapter or section, that page will only contain the title of the chapter or section, with the letter in the next page, and it looks awful.
2. There will be hundreds of letters, which means having hundreds of short separate `.tex` documents, which I don't like because it will get too confusing. It means for example I can't search and replace in a single document.

Please, let me know what I could try.

Comment: Are these letters which haven't been written yet (fake letters)?

Comment: Keeping the letters as separate `.tex` files seems to me to be preferable, since you can have a sensible way of keeping track of them (e.g. very clear filenames). If you really need to do search and replace over multiple files, there are many text editors that can do this.  But the letters themselves shouldn't be self-contained `.tex` documents, (i.e., no preamble and `\begin{document}` or `\end{document}` but just the contents that can then be `\input` into your main book document. Depending on how the actual book is put together the files could even be `\input` simply using a loop.

Comment: cont. The commands used in the `letter` class can be added to your book preamble along with a `letter` environment if needed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo They are real letters, but not typed yet into the computer, so could be considered fake.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'd still prefer to have a single document, but if keeping them as separate .tex files is the way to go, I'm happy to do so. I had tried that, but I was unable to find a way to keep the main document as book type, and the non-self-contained letter .tex files as letter type. You mentioned I can do so through a letter environment, could you please indicate how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very quick and dirty solution, very lightly tested. Basically I've cannibalized the `letter.cls` for most of its code and put it into a package form. Then you can use the `letter` environment inside your book. I've used the code from `letter.cls` only for expediency. If you haven't entered any of the letters yet, then you have no need to use the `letter` class code directly, but make a simpler package that contains a `letter` environment, and any of the other markup commands you would require (`\to`, `\from`, `\opening` and `\closing`, etc.) One thing to note: the letters will not have separate page numbers internal to the letter as they would if e.g., you had included them using `pdfpages`; if you need that the method would need some significant modification.

If you really have hundreds of letters it seems to me that you would be much better off storing each letter as a separate file (basically just the `letter` environment), keeping track of them with an Excel spreadsheet in CSV form and then using `datatool` to `\input` the files. This would make management much easier I think than a single enormous file.

### `letter-package.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{letter-package}[2019/08/09 package version of letter.cls]
% The following code is taken directly from the letter.cls 
% The {letter} environment has been simplified for inclusion into another document
% Proof of concept. Very lightly tested. Use at your own risk.
% It’s likely this code could be simplified further but using the actual code
% from the class allows a kind of backwards compatibility.
% 
\newenvironment{letter}[1]
  {\@processto{\leavevmode\ignorespaces #1}}
  {\par}
\long\def\@processto#1{%
  \@xproc #1\\@@@%
  \ifx\toaddress\@empty
  \else
    \@yproc #1@@@%
  \fi}
\long\def\@xproc #1\\#2@@@{\def\toname{#1}\def\toaddress{#2}}
\long\def\@yproc #1\\#2@@@{\def\toaddress{#2}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\@nobreakvspace
   {\@ifstar\@nobreakvspacex\@nobreakvspacex}
\def\@nobreakvspacex#1{%
  \ifvmode
    \nobreak\vskip #1\relax
  \else
    \@bsphack\vadjust{\nobreak\vskip #1}\@esphack
  \fi}
\def\@nobreakcr{\@ifstar{\@normalcr*}{\@normalcr*}}
\newdimen\longindentation
\longindentation=.5\textwidth
\newdimen\indentedwidth
\indentedwidth=\textwidth
\advance\indentedwidth -\longindentation
\newcommand*{\name}[1]{\def\fromname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\signature}[1]{\def\fromsig{#1}}
\newcommand*{\address}[1]{\def\fromaddress{#1}}
\newcommand*{\location}[1]{\def\fromlocation{#1}}
\newcommand*{\telephone}[1]{\def\telephonenum{#1}}
\name{}
\signature{}
\address{}
\location{}
\telephone{}
\newcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\newcommand{\closing}[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  \noindent
  \ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else
  \hspace*{\longindentation}\fi
  \parbox{\indentedwidth}{\raggedright
       \ignorespaces #1\\[6\medskipamount]%
       \ifx\@empty\fromsig
           \fromname
       \else \fromsig \fi\strut}%
   \par}
\medskipamount=\parskip
\newcommand*{\cc}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
    \@hangfrom{\normalfont\ccname: }%
    \ignorespaces #1\strut}\par}
\newcommand*{\encl}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
    \@hangfrom{\normalfont\enclname: }%
    \ignorespaces #1\strut}\par}
\newcommand*{\stopbreaks}{%
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \def\par{\@@par\nobreak}%
  \let\\\@nobreakcr
  \let\vspace\@nobreakvspace}
\DeclareRobustCommand\@nobreakvspace
   {\@ifstar\@nobreakvspacex\@nobreakvspacex}
\def\@nobreakvspacex#1{%
  \ifvmode
    \nobreak\vskip #1\relax
  \else
    \@bsphack\vadjust{\nobreak\vskip #1}\@esphack
  \fi}
\def\@nobreakcr{\@ifstar{\@normalcr*}{\@normalcr*}}
\newcommand*{\startbreaks}{%
  \let\\\@normalcr
  \interlinepenalty 200%
  \def\par{\@@par\penalty 200\relax}}
\newcommand*{\ps}{\par\startbreaks}
\newcommand*{\stopletter}{}
\newcommand*{\returnaddress}{}
\newcommand*{\ccname}{cc}
\newcommand*{\enclname}{encl}
\newcommand*{\pagename}{Page}
\newcommand*{\headtoname}{To}
\endinput
```

### Sample document

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{letter-package}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{letter}{}
\signature{Me}
\address{This place}
\date{1 1 1111}

\opening{Dear you:}
\kant[1]
\closing{Bye,}
\ps{PS}
\end{letter}
\begin{letter}{}
\signature{Someone}
\address{That place}
\date{2 2 2222}

\opening{Dear person:}
\kant[2]
\closing{Yours truly,}
\ps{PS}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this works fine, but I would be really grateful if you could modify that letter-package.sty file so that it would keep the same formatting as the letter package does (for example spacing is not the same). I tried to do it with no success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zynk I might be able to do that, but your description is much too vague to give me a sense of what you need. As I said, there's no real need to use the `letter` class code at all; it would probably be simpler to adapt the basic commands and then create a formatting that is pleasing to you.  For example I would probably put letters into some sort of a `quote` style environment (with smaller margins than the main text). But my answer was more proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Either the letter class code, or the quote style environment is fine for me. What you provided works perfectly, I would only like it to keep exactly the same space formatting as the original letter class does.

Comment: @Zynk Sorry but I still have no idea what that means in this context Spacing is simply too vague a term. Anyway, it's not that hard to make formatting that suits your purposes.  If you have trouble with that, ask a separate question. For a highly customizable quote environment, I recommend the `quoting` package.

Comment: I just want exactly the same that you provided but with the same space distance between paragraphs as a simple letter document provides out of the box in LaTeX.